# MySQL MERGE Storage Engine

Tags: mysql

I am setting up a table in mysql of engine type merge in mysql and was wondering if i have to have all my tables created previously that i want to merge. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE t2 (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO t1 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t1');
INSERT INTO t2 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t2');
CREATE TABLE total (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   message CHAR(20), INDEX(a))
   ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

Now if i have code that automatically created a t3 table i would have to modify the merge table to add this to the union? Would i use an ALTER query for that?

note: i am not using MySQL partitions because i have a mysql version 5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now if i have code that automatically created a t3 table i would have to modify the merge table to add this to the union? Would i use an ALTER query for that?

From the [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html):

> To remap a `MERGE` table to a different collection of `MyISAM` tables, you can use one of the following methods:
>
> - `DROP` the `MERGE` table and re-create it.
> - Use `ALTER TABLE tbl_name UNION=(...)` to change the list of underlying tables.
>
> Beginning with `MySQL` 5.0.60, it is also possible to use A`LTER TABLE ... UNION=()` (that is, with an empty `UNION` clause) to remove all of the underlying tables.

Comment: WHEN INSERT_METHOD = NO THEN INSERT METHOD IS return ERROR :  ERROR 1036 (HY000): Table  is read only